# How to change one button's title based on another button's state in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button

I'm very new to objective-c. This is what I want to achieve:

I have two buttons named buttonOne and buttonTwo. The default title of buttonOne is "One". Now, when I touch buttonTwo, I want it to stay highlighted (background changes) like being pressed and at the same time I want the title of buttonOne to change to "Two". When I touch buttonTwo again, I want it to change back to its normal state and also the title of buttonOne will change back to "One". I've done something like this:

```
[_buttonTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTwoPressed:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[_buttonTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTwoReleased:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (IBAction)buttonTwoPressed:(id)sender {
[_buttonOne setTitle:@"Two" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
}

- (IBAction)buttonTwoReleased:(id)sender {
[_buttonOne setTitle:@"One" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

This doesn't work properly. When I touch buttonTwo, the background the buttonTwo changes but the title of buttonOne doesn't change.I have to constantly hold down buttonTwo to see the title of buttonOne change to "Two". Also, when I touch buttonTwo again, nothing happens.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are resetting the title to "One" right ? So what are you expecting then.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, you are resetting the title immediately when user takes the finger off from the button.

You can do it using a single method:

```
[_buttonTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTwoPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Implement the method like:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTwoPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
   sender.selected = !sender.selected;
   if (sender.selected)
   {
     [_buttonOne setTitle:@"Two" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
   }
   else
   {
     [_buttonOne setTitle:@"One" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are circumstances that you may have overlooked in this implementation.  For example, because you have no action on control event UIControlEventTouchUpOutside, you can catch the change of state on touch down but miss the change back because the touch area moves before the touch event ends (drag off the button before releasing/touchUp..)

I'd be looking at catching the change of control state rather than touchEvents.  Unfortunately -(UIControlState )state is read only.  so there is no setter to override, but we can catch the events which immediately precede/cause the change of controlState. This is UIControl stuff, let's call this strategyA
Another approach might be to override the touch events from UIView, lets call this strategyB.
Both of these strategies leverage the default implementation, so it's important to pass the message on to super(superclass, i.e. what would happen if we didn't implement the method at all) before we inform our delegate

Subclass UIButton and do something like this.  Don't forget you'll need to go change out the class of your buttons in your nib or storyboard or whatever you've done to set them up..

interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol StateButtonDelegate;

@interface StateButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<StateButtonDelegate> delegate;
@end


@protocol StateButtonDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)button:(StateButton *)button didChangeState:(UIControlState )newState;
@end
```

implementation:

```
    //  StateButton.m
    #import "StateButton.h"

    @implementation StateButton

//strategyA 

    -(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected{
      [super setSelected:selected];
      [self.delegate button:self didChangeState:self.state];
    }
    -(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted{  
      [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
      [self.delegate button:self didChangeState:self.state];
    }
    -(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled{
      [super setEnabled:enabled];
      [self.delegate button:self didChangeState:self.state];
    }

//or
//strategyB

-(void )touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
  [self.delegate button:self didChangeState:self.state];
}
-(void )touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
  [self.delegate button:self didChangeState:self.state];
}
-(void )touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
  [self.delegate button:self didChangeState:self.state];
}
    @end
```

then add the protocol to your controller, set it delegate to both buttons and you might have some control

```
 -(void)button:(StateButton *)button didChangeState:(UIControlState )newState{

if (button == _buttonOne){

  if (newState & UIControlStateNormal){
    //doStuff
    }else if (newState & UIControlStateHighlighted){
    //doOtherStuff
    }else if (newState & UIControlStateSelected){
    //doDifferentStuffAgain
    } 
}else if (button == _buttonTwo){

   if (newState & UIControlStateNormal){
    //doStuff
    }else if (newState & UIControlStateHighlighted){
    //doOtherStuff
    }else if (newState & UIControlStateSelected){
    //doDifferentStuffAgain
    } 
  }  
}
```